# Error while adding user through LDAP using powershell

Tags: powershell, ldap

I am trying to add a user to an LDAP server. I am getting the next error:

```
Exception calling "SendRequest" with "1" argument(s): "The type is not defined."
At line:11 char:1
+ $response = $connection.SendRequest($request)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirectoryOperationException
```

This is my code:

```
$credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.NetworkCredential -ArgumentList ($ldapUser, $ldapPass)
$directoryIdentifier = New-Object -TypeName System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapDirectoryIdentifier -ArgumentList ($ldapServer, $ldapPort)
$connection = New-Object -TypeName System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection -ArgumentList ($directoryIdentifier, $credential, [DirectoryServices.Protocols.AuthType]::Basic)
$connection.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3
$connection.Bind()



$request = New-Object -TypeName System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.AddRequest
$request.DistinguishedName = "uid=Test_Thomas,ou=Users,ou=DE,ou=saria,dc=ext,dc=saria,dc=com"
$request.Attributes.Add((New-Object -TypeName System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryAttribute -ArgumentList "objectclass", @("top","organizationalPerson","person","inetorgperson"))) | Out-Null
$request.Attributes.Add((New-Object -TypeName System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryAttribute -ArgumentList "cn", $ExistingFrontlineWorkers[1].cn)) | Out-Null
$request.Attributes.Add((New-Object -TypeName System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryAttribute -ArgumentList "sn", $ExistingFrontlineWorkers[1].sn)) | Out-Null
$request.Attributes.Add((New-Object -TypeName System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryAttribute -ArgumentList "mail", $ExistingFrontlineWorkers[1].mail)) | Out-Null
$request.Attributes.Add((New-Object -TypeName System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryAttribute -ArgumentList "uid", "Test_Thomas")) | Out-Null
$request.Attributes.Add((New-Object -TypeName System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryAttribute -ArgumentList "uidNumber", "1000")) | Out-Null
$request.Attributes.Add((New-Object -TypeName System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryAttribute -ArgumentList "gidNumber", "1000")) | Out-Null
$request.Attributes.Add((New-Object -TypeName System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryAttribute -ArgumentList "homeDirectory", "")) | Out-Null
$response = $connection.SendRequest($request)
```

There isn´t a problem with the connection because I can search.

Comment: Is it undefined LDAP or ActiveDirectory LDAP? Which version of PS you use?

Comment: OpenLDAP, PS version 5.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `DirectoryOperationException` meaning that LDAP service (server) is unwilling to perform this request.

For example, if your LDAP service is ActiveDirectory, you MUST create user with `userAccountControl` disabled flag (or to set password instead), you MUST set user's distinguished name as `CN=Test_Thomas instead` of `uid=Test_Thomas`, etc...

If you use PS5+, you can use `::new()` instead of `new-object`  like this.

Warning: this code is not tested.

```
$request = [System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.AddRequest]::new(
    'CN=username,OU=Users,DC=contoso,DC=com',
    @(
        [System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryAttribute]::new('samaccountname', 'username')
        # ref https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/useraccountcontrol-manipulate-account-properties
        # Create account disabled as it has no password yet
        [System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryAttribute]::new('userAccountControl', 514) 
        [System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryAttribute]::new('userPrincipalName', 'username@contoso.com') 
        [System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryAttribute]::new('displayName', 'username') 
        [System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryAttribute]::new('objectClass', @('top', 'person', 'organizationalPerson', 'user')) 
        [System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryAttribute]::new('objectCategory', 'CN=Person,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=contoso,DC=com') 
        [System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryAttribute]::new('distinguishedName', 'CN=username,OU=Users,DC=contoso,DC=com') 
        [System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryAttribute]::new('instanceType', 4) 
    )
)
```

Read more or search examples

http://pig.made-it.com/pig-adusers.html

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adod/1fd2c193-fc70-4f90-a8c8-f1ca2de4e5ac

https://gist.github.com/leosouzadias/0f5acd0b70e86f811e25a8fd327db7dc

https://github.com/zorn96/ms_active_directory/blob/main/ms_active_directory/core/ad_session.py#L338

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I will try that next week.